# Fix broken element that miss ending tag or /> with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Is there a simple way to fix elements in a html document that miss the ending tag, or /> ending? 
I'm using ASP.NET with c# (loads html with the help of Html Agility Pack).

An example:

```
<img src="www.example.com/image.jpg">
```

should transform into

```
<img src="www.example.com/image.jpg" />
```

or

```
<img src="www.example.com/image.jpg"></img>
```

Comment: If you can load the HTML with the Agility Pack - where is the actual problem?

Comment: @Tomalak - I am assuming he wants to genarete a valid XHTML document from the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the save() method to convert the Html document to XML. Doing this, HTMLAgilitypack will  try to close all the open tags.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);    
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Xml.XmlTextWriter xw = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(sw);
doc.Save(xw);
string result = sw.ToString();
```